# meaning of "Snuffed its rich scent" in "Animal farm" book

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "snuffed its reach scent" in "they kicked up clods of the black earth and snuffed its rich scent" in "Animal Farm" book?

Comment: Did you mean [_snuffled_](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snuffle) which seems to be the original text?

Comment: Hello, 350. What do dictionaries say a possible meaning of 'snuff' is here? Obviously, it's a verb here, and 'to snuff it' (= 'die') is something entirely different.

Comment: I mistakenly upvoted KillingTime. Numerous versions of the text show 'snuffed' - "to draw air into the nostrils by inhaling, as to smell something; snuffle" - Dictionary.com

Comment: In my version of book, it is "snuffed" not "snuffled"